# Kotlin SIZE_BYTES

Tags: kotlin

I have a question related to the following code:

```
fun main() {
    println(Char.SIZE_BYTES)

    val x = 'x'
    println(x.SIZE_BYTES)
}
```

The first print statement works fine, and correctly prints out 2, however the second one causes a compile error with unknown reference = SIZE_BYTES. The val x is a Char, so why am I not able to use the SIZE_BYTES on it?

compile error: Unresolved reference: SIZE_BYTES

Comment: If you're coming from a language like Python where class methods can be called on instances fluidly, this may seem strange at first. But Kotlin's philosophy is different, and Tenfour's answer describes the Kotlin way of thinking perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions and properties of a companion object are not also functions and properties of every instance of that class. When you call `Char.SIZE_BYTES`, it is actually shorthand syntax for `Char.Companion.SIZE_BYTES`.

`Char.Companion` is a `companion object`. It is a distinct class from `Char` that carries data that is related to `Char`s, but it is not a `Char` itself, and `Char`s are not `Char.Companion`s either.

An `object` is a class with no constructor and that is automatically instantiated the first time it is referenced. It only ever has one instance, and you can reference this instance by the `object'`s name directly. A `companion object` is an `object` that allows you to omit calling it by its own name. You can use its related class's name alone without `.Companion` (the default name when you don't name it) or whatever you have named it.